# Insert a line at specific position if file contains a certain string

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

I would like to insert a string in `line 2` of every file that contain a specific string somewhere in the file.

Like 
`sed '1 a #This is just a commented line' -i`

but only if file contains the string: 

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your command,

```
sed -i '1 a #This is just a commented line'
```

works for a given file.

To apply this to some file, `somefile`, if the file contains the string `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">`, you may use

```
if grep -q -F '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">' somefile
then
    sed -i '1 a #This is just a commented line' somefile
fi
```

The `-q` option to `grep` causes the utility to stop at the first match, and to not output anything (we're only interested in the exit status).  The `-F` option will make `grep` treat the given pattern as a string rather than as a regular expression.

To apply this to all files in the current directory (skipping files that are not regular files or symbolic links to regular files):

```
pattern='<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">'

for name in ./*; do
    [ ! -f "$name" ] && continue
    if grep -q -F -e "$pattern" "$name"; then
        sed -i '1 a #This is just a commented line' "$name"
    fi
done
```

I'm using `-e "$pattern"`, with the `-e` option, here. It's a good habit to specify the pattern for `grep` with `-e` when the pattern is kept in a variable.  There may be situation where the variable's value starts with a dash (not in this specific problem, obviously), and this would confuse `grep` if `-e` is not used, making it think that the pattern is actually some command line option.

To do this for all files in or below the current directory:

```
pattern='<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">'

find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    pattern=$1; shift
    for name do
        if grep -q -F -e "$pattern" "$name"; then
            sed -i "1 a #This is just a commented line" "$name"
        fi
    done' sh "$pattern" {} +
```

This executes a short inline `sh -c` script for batches of found files, passing the pattern as the first command line argument to the script and the found pathnames as the remaining arguments.

or, to let `find` use `grep` as a test and then execute `sed` on the files that passes the test,

```
pattern='<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-7">'

find . -type f \
    -exec grep -q -F -e "$pattern" {} \; \
    -exec sed -i '1 a #This is just a commented line' {} +
```

By using `{} +` instead of `{} \;` at the end of the `sed` command above, we give `sed` as many input files as possible at once rather than executing `sed` once for each file.  This requires GNU `sed` to work properly, but since you're already using GNU `sed` syntax in your `a` command, I'm assuming that is ok.

See also [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)